# Why is the filter output not in sin form?

Tags: filter, dsp, simulink

The lowpass filters I created with the Matlab fda tool are different from the sinus form in the simulation.
What could be the reason for this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Showing the input signals and the output signals would help us answer your question.

Comment: Response Type: Lowpass
Design Method: FIR (Window)
Filter Order: Specify order (7)
Options: Window (Kaiser)
Frequency Specifications:
Fs: 20 000 Hz
Fc: 2000 Hz

In this setup, we have a 500 Hz main signal and we use a high frequency (8000 Hz) signal to get a noisy signal.

Comment: Looks as expected for a sudden sinewave application. What would you have expected? What is the bode plot for the filter you wanted?

Comment: 1. Your 2nd input is not a pure sinusoid. 2. The output looks pretty close to a sine to me. Have you tried looking at the spectra of the inputs and outputs and comparing to see if the filter is behaving as expected?